# How to read the data from iOS 13 NFC

Tags: swift, iphone, nfc, ios13

Can any body suggest working examples to read data from epassport via NFC chip using BAC/PACE.
I know that there are lot of steps to implement BAC/PACE.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

Comment: https://medium.com/appcoda-tutorials/building-nfc-product-scanner-ios-app-with-corenfc-alfian-losari-5da0365bcde5

Comment: Thank you for sharing the URLs. But I am looking for the example which is implemented BAC/PACE protocol to read e-passport NFC data.